# Rails rollback deploy AND master to ref while preserving failure in new branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I have run into trouble with a recent production (well, staging actually but we'll keep calling it 'production') deployment.

I'd like to (read: need to) roll back the deploy to a previous commit. Actually, I'd like to go back a ways and then move forward `cap deploy`ing each commit one by one until I see the problem materialize. I know I can use `cap -S revision=8c9ffa787b22cff019b27f71194637aa85506f9c deploy` to deploy a specific commit.

My question is, when I FIND the commit I want to stick with how can I reset `HEAD` and `master`, etc. so that basically, master points to that commit and, ideally, all the subsequent commits are captured in a new branch of some name, say `rabbithole`?

Need to do this w/out fouling the git repos in development, **GitHub** and then the `cached-copy` that **Capistrano** automatically creates on production server.

Hope I'm making sense. If not please ask for more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you want to revert all commits between you stable commit and you HEAD. Check this

```
git checkout master
git revert XXSHAXX..HEAD
```

Where XXSHAXX is your stable commit.
This will create a bunch of new commits - one for each after stable. As a result you'll have a new commit equivalent to you stable in HEAD and none of your history will be lost.

P.S. and you wont be beaten by others who works in same repo.

Answer (score 0):

To rollback to a previous commit

`cap deploy:rollback`

To rollback to a previously deployed commit

`cap deploy:rollback:code`

Once you've found a commit that you want to keep at master, you *can* do a rebase. Not sure if this is the best route, as you should always be wary of forcing an update on master.

I would temporarily change the branch where my `staging` environment is pulling from, rather than push a forced update on master upstream.

Ok, warnings aside:

```
$ git checkout master; git checkout -b master-backup-before-rebase; git checkout master
```

There might be a quicker/simpler way to do this, but we basically ensure we're on `master`, create a new branch called `master-backup-before-rebase`, and then go back to master.

```
$ git rebase -i head~XXX
```

Replace ~XXX with however many commits back you want to remove + 1.

Next, a text editor window will open - remove the lines of all commits you want to delete. Save, and close the window.

```
$ git push origin master -f
```

Voila.

Be very careful with this, and **ensure that your backup branch exists** before rebasing, lest you accidentally remain on the Master branch because you had uncommitted local changes or something.